# Inject EventDispatcher into an Entity in a DDD way

Tags: service, domain-driven-design, event-dispatching

is it correct in a DDD way to inject an EventDispatcher into an entity?

Imagine that I have a DomainModel called Card. This card in an ubiquitous language can be activated and deactivated. But the activation and deactivation involves a call to a third party API that it activates in the real world.

So to keep our Domain Models clear my approach is my Card entity has a activate method that looks like:

```
public function activate()
{
    $this->active = true;

    $this->dispatcher->dispatch(CardEvents::CARD_ACTIVATION, new CardActivation($this));
}
```

Then a service is listening the dispatcher to activate or not activate using an external API.

Is it correct to inject into an entity this EventDispatcher?

What is the approach if the call to the api fails?

Has any sense that the listening service changes finally the active property of the Card itself?

Thanks.

Comment: You could rely on a simple synchronous event dispatcher (no full-blown messaging mechanism) as a static class. You would do something like `DomainEvents.raise(...)` from within the domain entity. Since the event would be processed synchronously, it would be processed in the same transaction. Another solution would be to pass an `ICardActivator` to the `activate` function such as `card.activate(activator)`. Finally, you could as well just call upon the service in the application layer. `card.activate(); cardService.activate(card);`.

Comment: Some people also records the events in the entity and the repository or application service would be responsible for publishing them.

Comment: Check this out https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

If this EventDispatcher inside the activate method is just a reference to an interface from the domain, then yes, it's ok. Then you would expose this interface from your domain to another layer and create a class (e.g in the application layer) implementing said interface, and this class could be implemented using a third party library or anything else. That way, your domain don't know how the `IEventDispatcher` interface is implemented, keeping it safe from changes.

Keep in mind changing the way this EventDispatcher is implemented (if it uses a third-party plugin, or if you implemented by yourself) shouldn't affect your domain/business logic. Maybe the application consuming it could be affected. You could have many applications (web, mobile, desktop) with the possibility to deactive a Card, each one with a different EventDispatcher version/implementation (or the same), and this can't affect your domain. If it does, then you should review your design.

Moreover, I'd keep the EventDispatcher inside your Card model only if you must call it regardless of what application (web, desktop, mobile, webservice) is requesting the `activate()` method, which means calling the `dispatch()` method of **some EventDispatcher** is part of your business logic (note the emphasis on the *some* word, since the domain doesn't know anything about how it is implemented, it ), just because your domain want to give the application a chance of doing a *dispatch*, no matter if it works or not, if it does something or not (the domain doesn't care about it, it just calls it).